# how to set dropdownList from the value passed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a table which has 4 td. On the fourth td i have created one button . On clicking that button i am calling a function populateDropdownfromselectecd("strategyTypeId${loop.index}") and passing one of the td Id to that function. Inside that function i am calling a dialog box, which has one dropDownList . The dropDownList contains the one of the values which i have stored in variable "strategyType" . Now what I want to do is when i open the dialog box that value should already be selected

this is my table from where i am calling the function

```
<c:forEach var="main" items="${currentProfitAndLossByStrategyTypeMap}" varStatus="loop">
<tr>
  <td id="strategyTypeId${loop.index}"><c:out value="${main.key}"/></td>
  <td><c:out value="${main.value}"/></td>
  <td id="clickToTrade"><button onclick='populateDropdownfromselectecd("strategyTypeId${loop.index}")'>Click to Trade</button></td>
</tr>   
</c:forEach>
```

This is the function i Have written

```
function populateDropdownfromselectecd(StrategyValue)
{
 var strategyType = document.getElementById(StrategyValue).innerHTML;
 //alert(strategyType); 
 $('#settingsDialog').dialog('open');
}
```

I tried something which didn't work

```
function populateDropdownfromselectecd(StrategyValue)
{
 var strategyType = document.getElementById(StrategyValue).innerHTML;
 //alert(strategyType); 
 $('#settingsDialog').dialog('open').$('#selectStrategy').val(strategyType);
}
```

Comment: a working fiddle would help us help you with your question...

Comment: @OmasuPlus  how to add fiddle

Comment: create a fiddle here https://fiddle.jshell.net/ which demonstrates what you have done and shows what your problem is...

Comment: Try this - first open the dialog and then set the value. $('#settingsDialog').dialog('open');  $('#settingsDialog #selectStrategy').val(strategyType);

Comment: @T.Shah That's not working .